# check if image exists php

Tags: php

I am in the middle of coding up a property portal. I am stuck on checking images. I know how to check if an image url is set. But the problem is detecting if there is actually a valid image at the url.

example : http://property.images.themovechannel.com/cache/7217/6094437/img_main.jpg

This image url exists but the image is has now been removed so it just displays blank in my propety search page. Is there a way of checking there is an image there at the url  and then displaying a placeholder if it doesnt exist.

something like

```
$imageURL = "http://property.images.themovechannel.com/cache/7217/6094437/img_main.jpg";

if (exists($imageURL)) { display image } 
else { display placeholder }
```

But all this does is check the url exists, which it does there is just no image there

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you can look for an <img> tag in the returned HTML?

Comment: I was thinking of that but the page is quite big kind of wanted to do it all on the fly with php

Comment: Could you post a link to an image that _does_ exist?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to ensure that the URL points to a valid image.

```
if (getimagesize($imageURL) !== false) {
    // display image
}
```

Comment: It's very slow function for external URI.

Comment: if file doesn't exist it cause php Notice. Use this function with "@" is bad manner, so I think better way is that @plutov.by described

Answer (score 8):

```
function exists($uri)
{
    $ch = curl_init($uri);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $code == 200;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function is_webUrl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    // don't download content
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    if (curl_exec($ch) !== FALSE) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

if(is_webUrl('http://www.themes.tatwerat.com/wp/ah-personal/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/features-ah-wp-view.jpg')) {
   echo 'yes i found it';
}else{
   echo 'file not found';
}
```