# file_exists returning false in all cases

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on Wordpress at the moment and as simple as it's sounds i'm trying to check if the image is there in the directory if not then it will show a standard no-image.

My problem is that the `file_exists` is returning false although the url is correct inside it, and it's accessible via browser so it's not a permission issue, and maybe i'm doing it wrong, here's the code;

```
$img = 'no_img.jpg';
if($val->has_prop('user_image')){
$img_tmp = $val->get( 'user_image' );
        if(file_exists($upload_dir['baseurl'].'/users/'.$img_tmp)){
$img = $val->get( 'user_image' );
    }
}
```

if i do `var_dump($upload_dir['baseurl'].'/users/'.$img_tmp);` it will show the exact direct URL to the file, and it's correct one, but when it enters the `file_exists` it returns `$img = 'no_img.jpg'` although the file exists in the directory.... What am i doing wrong??

I tried also to add `clearstatcache();` before the `file_exists` but didn't work also.
Any ideas?

Comment: What's in `$upload_dir["baseurl"]`?

Comment: @Maerlyn http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir , it return the URL of the upload directory in WP

Comment: `file_exists` works with path of file, not url.

Comment: is "direct URI" actually relative or absolute? You might be assuming the wrong *working directory*

Comment: When i did that `var_dump` it will return `http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/users/file.jpg`, it's a full path to the file image...

Comment: You should try to use [getimagesize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970322/check-if-image-exists-php).

Comment: @Liza, no it's **url** of file full path will be somethisg like `/home/user/workspace/folder/users/imp.png` OR `C://path/to/folder/img.png` if you use Windows

Comment: @Liza you must use a path, not a URI, like `wp-content/uploads/users/file.jpg` if you're using file_exists from the WP root

Comment: you can use `$fullPath=$upload_dir['baseurl'].'/users/'.$img_tmp;  if(@fopen($fullPath,"r"))`

Comment: Check `@file_get_contents($upload_dir['baseurl'].'/users/'.$img_tmp, null, null, 0, 1);` to see if the path is correct and the file actually exists. If it returns anything, it is OK.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments, i changed to @Nouphal.M method of `@fopen`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
$fullPath=$upload_dir['baseurl'].'/users/'.$img_tmp; 

if(@fopen($fullPath,"r")){
     ........
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use:

```
if( getimagesize($upload_dir['baseurl'].'/users/'.$img_tmp) !== false ){
    $img = $val->get( 'user_image' );
}
else {
    $img = $val->get( 'no_image' );
}
```

Also refer to the doc [getimagesize](http://www.php.net/getimagesize)

Answer (score 1):

Or as mentioned in comments, try sniff instead :

```
if (@file_get_contents($upload_dir['baseurl'].'/users/'.$img_tmp, null, null, 0, 1)) {
    //ok
}
```

Comment: That seems like a bad practice. Reminds me of fixing WP RSS feeds with linebreaks at the top (due to bad plugins) with CURLand trim (that actually happened)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use $upload_dir['**basedir**'] instead of **baseurl** if you used **$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();** to determine the upload path of your WP installation.

or you can use **file_get_contents, cURL, or fopen** to sniff if image exists for the url.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! +1 for it

Comment: great.. hope that helped!!