# file_exists($url) does not work in case of ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a file called 'test.php' inside the file i have the following code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn").click(function(){
            jQuery.ajax({
                url : 'http://example.com/TEST/images.php',
                type : 'POST',
                data : {
                     name : 'black-ring1.gif'
                },
                success : function(data, status) {
                    if(data){
                       alert(data);
                    }
                }


            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p id="btn">Button</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My 'images.php' file which executes when ajax called conteains the following code.

```
<?php
$image_name = $_POST['name'];
$src = "http://example.com/images/icons/" . $image_name;

if(file_exists($src)){
    echo "Exists";
}else{
    echo "Does not exist";
}
```

inside  the 'images.php' file_exists($url) gives me always wrong answer(Does not exist).. I am sure $url really exits in the given url.. But why it does not work. How i can make it work ... Please help me..  Thanks..

Comment: `file_exists()` checks files. A URL is not a file.

Comment: You might be able to use `file_get_contents()` in this situation or maybe take advantage of curl as they both allow use of URLs. `file_get_contents() === false` on error. If you have local access to the file you should use a local file path and basic file operations as they are better performance in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

`file_exists` can't be used with `http://` URLs. From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php):

> As of PHP 5.0.0, this function can also be used with some URL wrappers. Refer to [Supported Protocols and Wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) to determine which wrappers support `stat()` family of functionality.

If you follow that link and then follow the [`http://`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) link, it says:

> Supports stat() No

Instead, you can simply try to open the URL. If it succeeds then the URL exists.

```
<?php
$image_name = $_POST['name'];
$src = "http://example.com/images/icons/" . $image_name;

if($fh = fopen($src)){
    echo "Exists";
    close($fh);
}else{
    echo "Does not exist";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to validate that you pass the name

```
(!empty($_POST["name"])) {
  $image_name = $_POST['name'];
  $src = "http://example.com/images/icons/" . $image_name;
}else{  
    echo "no, name";
}
```

then you can use CURL to check if the url exist

```
if(is_url_exist($src)){
    echo "Exists";
}else{
    echo "Does not exist";
}
```

this code is from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684771/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-from-a-url)

```
function is_url_exist($url){
    $ch = curl_init($url);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if($code == 200){
       $status = true;
    }else{
      $status = false;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
   return $status;
}
```

you can also try from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970322/check-if-image-exists-php)

```
if (getimagesize($src) !== false) {
        echo "Exists";
    }else{
        echo "Does not exist";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

file_exists() checks files. A URL is not a file. If the image file you're looking for is on your local server, then you can just use the full path name to it:

```
if (file_exists('/path/to/images/foo.png')) {
    ...
}
```

If the file is on a remote server, and you want to test that the URL referencing it is valid, you might use CURL to perform a HEAD request against it:

```
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'HEAD');
$result = curl_exec($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($info['http_code'] == 200) {
    echo "image exists\n";
}
```

I would not recommend doing something like `file_get_contents($url)` unless you actually need the image contents, because this will actually download the full image and then just throw it away, wasting bandwidth for both you and the remote server.